# Openssl Generate a base64-encoded public key - Access to the path 'C:\dev\null' is denied

Tags: openssl, public-key, google-pay

I m trying to generate the private/public keys for google pay integration. I m following the steps mentioned here https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#public-key-format I can generate the key and view the keys using the comment. When I tried to Generate a base64-encoded public key, I m getting the error as below

*out-file : Access to the path 'C:\dev\null' is denied.
At line:1 char:1

- openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout 2> /dev/null | grep "pub: ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand*
  ```

I have created the folder in C: and give the permission to fullcontrol still I m getting the access to the path is denied error.I tried the different Drive (D:) also, the same error.

Anyone Could you please help me on this ?[image]

Comment: I'm not able to resolve the issue with openssl. But I was able to generate the keys using git bash.